# Loading Properties with Spring (via System Properties)

Tags: spring, properties

My problem is as follows:

I have `server.properties` for different environments. The path to those properties is provided trough a system property called `propertyPath`. How can I instruct my `applicationContext.xml` to load the properties with the given `propertyPath` system property without some ugly `MethodInvokingBean` which calls `System.getProperty('');`

My applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="systemPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="sys{"/>
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="propertyPath">/default/path/to/server.properties</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" dependency-check="all" depends-on="systemPropertyConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg value="sys{propertyPath}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" ref="propertyResource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" ref="propertyResource"/>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="prop{"/>

        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
         <property name="jndiName" value="prop{datasource.name}"/>
    </bean>
```

with this configuration the propertyResource alsways complains about

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sys{propertyPath} (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Any suggestions? ;-)
Thanks gabe

EDIT:

Now I debugged the loading process of the beans and it seems the `setLocation` Method of the `propertyConfigurer` is called before the `systemPropertyConfigurer` is created so the propertyResource is initialized with "sys{propertyPath}".
I played around with `depends-on` but no luck.

Comment: how exactly did you play with depends-on?

Comment: 'propertyResource depends-on="systemPropertyConfigurer"' seems to have no effect. propertyResource is initialized first nontheless, maybe because it is initialized with constructor-arg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I solved it. The problem is both of my PropertyPlaceholders are BeanFactoryPostProcessor those get processed after the context is loaded but the properties are set after. So **it is impossible to populate one PropertyPlaceholder with another**.

### Here is my solution in code ;-)

```
package property.util;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * ConfigurablePropertyPlaceholder takes instructions which SystemProperty
 * contains the path to the propertyfile to load.
 *
 * @author Gabe Kaelin
 * 
 */
public class ConfigurablePropertyPlaceholder extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {


    private String propertyLocationSystemProperty;
    private String defaultPropertyFileName;


    public String getPropertyLocationSystemProperty() {
        return propertyLocationSystemProperty;
    }

    public void setPropertyLocationSystemProperty(String propertyLocationSystemProperty) {
        this.propertyLocationSystemProperty = propertyLocationSystemProperty;
    }

    public String getDefaultPropertyFileName() {
        return defaultPropertyFileName;
    }

    public void setDefaultPropertyFileName(String defaultPropertyFileName) {
        this.defaultPropertyFileName = defaultPropertyFileName;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to fill the location with the path from the {@link #propertyLocationSystemProperty}
     *
     * @param props propeties instance to fill
     * @throws IOException
     */

    @Override
    protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {
        Resource location = null;
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(propertyLocationSystemProperty)){

            String propertyFilePath = System.getProperties().getProperty(propertyLocationSystemProperty);
            StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder(propertyFilePath);

            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(defaultPropertyFileName) && !propertyFilePath.endsWith(defaultPropertyFileName)){
                pathBuilder.append("/").append(defaultPropertyFileName);
            }

            location = new FileSystemResource(pathBuilder.toString());
        }

        setLocation(location);
        super.loadProperties(props);
    }
}
```

The according applicationContext.xml entry

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="property.util.ConfigurablePropertyPlaceholder">
  <property name="propertyLocationSystemProperty" value="propertyPath" />
  <property name="defaultPropertyFileName" value="server.properties" />
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

the java process can be started with

```
java -DpropertyPath=/path/to/properties
```

and it loads the properties and they are available in the applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 2):

The solution given to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer seems ok but it should also work relying on the standard org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean implementation without writing any additional code.

Simply use the variable reference that will be resolved by Spring.

e.g.

Configure spring as follows:

```
<bean id="configProp"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:${propertyPath}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Once you invoke Java with the env variable (propertyPath), Spring will resolve it, load the property file and inject it into the application context

`java -DpropertyPath=/path/to/properties`

Comment: You can even configure default value when `propertyPath` has not been set: `${propertyPath:defaultValue}`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- use `sys:` as prefix (and hence `sys:propertyPath`)
- set the `placeholderSuffix` property of the placeholder configurer to `}`, so that you can access the properties with `sys{prop}`. If you omit this property, you will have to use `sys{prop`

Comment: Thank you for the tips. But I am unable to get it to work. Maybe I missed something. It always throws an FileNotFoundEx with the property name as file.

the default placeholderSuffix is } so there is no need to specify it

i think there is a problem with the loading order of the beans