# How to load properties of a bean dynamically in Spring

Tags: spring, properties

I am new to Spring framework and confused how to load properties of a bean ( Instance variables of a bean ) dynamically . Spring expects to use xml based configuration for declaring all the beans and dependencies between beans . 
For example ,

```
public class Bean1
   {
        int value; 
        public void setValue(int thisValue)
        {
             value = thisValue;
         }

   }
```

---

```
<bean id = "LibraryMgmtBean" class = "Bean1">
 <property name = "value" Value = "SampleString"/>   </bean>
```

But here we are mentioning all the properties of a bean statically . But , what if I want to supply these values dynamically . I mean , I may get values from a JSP page from weblayer and should pass to this bean .  And as all beans are declard in XML this way , how Spring Injects dependecies of other beans when all bean properties are supplied dynamically  ?

Comment: Do you want this dynamic or do you just want to know how a web app is build?

Comment: Might be both.... It will be helpful if i get any  good link that explains these  or specifically a good example of web application that built using Spring....... Thanx In advance for d help.....

Answer (score 0):

Found answers to my question from threads:

[How to collect spring properties from multiple files for use on a single bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534199/how-to-collect-spring-properties-from-multiple-files-for-use-on-a-single-bean)

[Apply dynamic properties to a bean at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008175/apply-dynamic-properties-to-a-bean-at-runtime)

[Loading Properties with Spring (via System Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789511/loading-properties-with-spring-via-system-properties)

Comment: This is not an answer, the question should've been flagged