# How to Inject an external properties file in spring context

Tags: java, spring, properties, jar

My question is an exact duplicate of this question : 
[Spring application context external properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8270290/1083581)

This is how I injected the props file before :

```
<util:properties id="smrProps" location="classpath:/spring/SomeProps.properties" />
```

But for the life of me, I cant figure out what to use in `location` when I want to inject a properties file which will be in the same directory as a runnable jar. I know where the classpath points and my props is just one level up, so I even tried `classpath:/../SomeProps.properties` assuming it will look in the parent folder, but no luck.

For ex if jar is in : `C:\temp\some.jar`and properties file is in `C:\temp\SomeProps.properties`

If some.jar is in temp, then SomeProps.properties will also be in temp. Of course, I cannot be using C:\temp\SomeProps.properties in location

Can someone please guide me on how I could use this props file ?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you can check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use a relative path to access something outside of the `.jar` with `util:properties`.

But, if you can, you should be able to do it by using a system property.

Also, you shoud use `file:` instead of `classpath:`. Something like this :

```
<util:properties id="smrProps" location="file:{my.path}/SomeProps.properties" />
```

And then execute the .jar with something like this :

```
java -Dmy.path=/YourFolderPath -jar application.jar
```

An other solution would be to extend the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and then get the path of the `.jar` with `Java`. Take a look at this question : [Loading Properties with Spring (via System Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789511/loading-properties-with-spring-via-system-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to figure out the path of running jar

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Use it find your prop file in parent folder and inject it into context using SPEL

Here is how it looks (you might want to tidy it a bit, but i was able to emulate your case and verified this solution):

```
<util:properties id="smrProps" location="'file:' + new java.io.File(T(com.yourpackage.YourClass).getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent() + '/'+ settings.prop'" />
```